# Operation with pandas data frame with several columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I'm trying to create some new columns in pandas, based on the values of existing columns, like in Excel. I'm not trying to find a value or match condition, so pd.where is not the solution. I wanna create a new column based on the variables (columns) I have for each row.

for ex. I would like to create a column 'D' with the condition : if pd['A'] > pd['C'] --> pd['D'] = 0, else pd['D'] = (pd['C']-pd['B'])*pd['A']

```
   B   A   C  D
0   1   2   3  4
1   4   20  6  0
2   7   8   9  40
3   10  11  12 22
4   13  24  15  0
```

but I'm getting the error

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,16).reshape(5,3),columns={'A','B','C'})

df['D'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: 0. if (x > df['C']) else (df['C']-df['B'])*df['A'] )
```

Comment: Use `df['D'] = np.where(df['A'] > df['C'], 0, (df['C']-df['B'])*df['A'] )`

Comment: I found the error, I only need to put the axis in my code, when I put axis=1, it works. Thank you.